# Django project cannot find application module

Tags: python, django

I am following the Tango with Django book's tutorial.
I tried to do:

```
from rango import views
```

in tango_with_django_project/urls.py where rango is the application. The IDE I use is pycharm and it cannot find or doesn't recognize rango.
The folder hierarchy is as follow:

```
rango
   __init__.py
     ...
   views.py

tango_with_django_project
   __init__.py
     ...
   urls.py
```

I already added 'rango' in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  .......
  'rango',
]
```

Any help or comment is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your importing from `range` but you say the application is `rango`

Comment: sorry, autocorrect changed 'rango' to 'range'

Answer (score 2):

You said

> pycharm ... cannot find or doesn't recognize rango

but you don't say if you have actually tried running the application. It could be just that pycharm doesn't know where to look for the code.

Try setting the top level folder of your project (the one you have the `tango_with_django_project` folder in) and mark it as a "Sources Root" by right-clicking on the folder and selecting the option from the "Mark Directory As" menu.

If that doesn't work, run your django app and add any error messages to your question.

[image: menu item]

Comment: I just found a solution to that which has to do with the directory I opened the project from - I think it's similar to what you suggested about Sources Root. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

include **rango** in **INSTALLED_APPS** within settings.py file as mentioned in below snippet

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  .......
  'rango',
]
```

Comment: I did that as well, still can't find it. Thank you for your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the level of directory I opened in PyCharm.
When I had the problem, I opened it from the topmost directory - which was why PyCharm couldn't find it.

```
rangoFolder

   tango_with_django_project

       rango
          __init__.py
            ...
          views.py

       tango_with_django_project
          __init__.py
            ...
          urls.py
```

When I opened the project from

```
   tango_with_django_project
           rango
              __init__.py
                ...
              views.py

           tango_with_django_project
              __init__.py
                ...
              urls.py
```

It found the module rango.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I use PyCharm, and I think it's great, but when it _suggests_ there is a problem it's always good to run the code to be sure there is/is not an error and it's not just PyCharm spooking you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences > Project Interpreter and set the project interpreter and path mapping. Also set the Project Structure accordingly.